# how use bokeh vbar chart parameter with groupby object?

Tags: python, bar-chart, data-visualization, bokeh

**Question**

Below code is grouped vbar chart example from bokeh documentation.
There are something i can't understand on this example.

> 1. Where 'cyl_mfr' is come from in factor_cmap() and vbar()?
> 2. 'mpg_mean' , is it calculating the mean of 'mpg' column? if then, 
>      why 'mpg_sum' doesn't work?

I want to make my own vbar chart like this example.

---

**Code**

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg_clean as df
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap

output_file("bars.html")

df.cyl = df.cyl.astype(str)
df.yr = df.yr.astype(str)

group = df.groupby(('cyl', 'mfr'))

source = ColumnDataSource(group)
index_cmap = factor_cmap('cyl_mfr', palette=Spectral5, 
factors=sorted(df.cyl.unique()), end=1)

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=300, title="Mean MPG by # Cylinders 
           and Manufacturer",
           x_range=group, toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x='cyl_mfr', top='mpg_mean', width=1, source=source,
       line_color="white", fill_color=index_cmap, )

p.y_range.start = 0
p.x_range.range_padding = 0.05
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Manufacturer grouped by # Cylinders"
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2
p.outline_line_color = None

p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[("MPG", "@mpg_mean"), ("Cyl, Mfr", 
            "@cyl_mfr")]))

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `group = df.groupby(('cyl', 'mfr'))` makes a `<pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0xxx>`. If you pass this to a `ColumnDataSource`, bokeh does a lot of magic, and calculates a lot of statistics already

```
df.columns
```

> ```
> Index(['mpg', 'cyl', 'displ', 'hp', 'weight', 'accel', 'yr', 'origin', 'name', 'mfr'],
> ```

```
source.column_names
```

> ['accel_count',  'accel_mean',  'accel_std',  'accel_min', 
>   'accel_25%',  'accel_50%',  'accel_75%',  'accel_max',  'displ_count',
>   'displ_mean',  'displ_std',  'displ_min',  'displ_25%',  'displ_50%', 
>   'displ_75%',  'displ_max',  'hp_count',  'hp_mean',  'hp_std', 
>   'hp_min',  'hp_25%',  'hp_50%',  'hp_75%',  'hp_max',  'mpg_count', 
>   'mpg_mean',  'mpg_std',  'mpg_min',  'mpg_25%',  'mpg_50%', 
>   'mpg_75%',  'mpg_max',  'weight_count',  'weight_mean',  'weight_std',
>   'weight_min',  'weight_25%',  'weight_50%',  'weight_75%', 
>   'weight_max',  'yr_count',  'yr_mean',  'yr_std',  'yr_min', 
>   'yr_25%',  'yr_50%',  'yr_75%',  'yr_max',  'cyl_mfr']

1. the `cyl_mfr` is the labels of the 2 columns on which you grouped by concatenated. In `source` this has become a column of tuples
2. `mpg_sum` is not calculated. If you cant the sum, you will need to calculate that yourself.

Comment: Just to be clear, it is Pandas that defines and computes a set of standard quantities on GroupBy's (when asked). Bokeh just makes them available easily in a CDS