# Trying to plot a pandas dataframe groupby with Bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, bokeh

New here but I've been searching for hours now and can't seem to find the solution for this. What I'm trying to do is display an aggregate of a dataframe in a Bokeh chart. I tried using a groupby object but I get an error when passing the groupby object to the ColumnDataSource (as mentioned in the post below).

[how use bokeh vbar chart parameter with groupby object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343429/how-use-bokeh-vbar-chart-parameter-with-groupby-object?s=1|65.3266)

Here's some sample code I'm using:

```
import pandas
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
group = df.groupby("A")
source = ColumnDataSource(group)
```

Getting this error:

```
ValueError: expected a dict or pandas.DataFrame, got <pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x103f7bfd0>
```

Any ideas as to plot the groupby object in a chart with Bokeh?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code works just fine for me (Pandas 0.21.0, Bokeh 0.12.11). Consider upgrading Pandas or/and Bokeh...

Comment: Thanks Max. I've got Pandas '0.20.3' and Bokey '0.12.5' installed so let me just tried upgrading to Pandas 0.21.1. Same error on my side though..

Comment: Never mind, upgraded to Bokeh 0.12.13 and now it works! Thanks Max!!

Comment: This was added in Bokeh 0.12.7 FYI https://bokeh.github.io/blog/2017/8/29/release-0-12-7/

Comment: Thanks!! That's very very useful!

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used Bokeh, however from what I see you are passing a `pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy` and `ColumnDataSource` is expecting a `pd.DataFrame`. That said the problem is that when using groupby you create a data structure that resembles key, value storage. So each group in the `groups` object will have a key and value, that value is the DataFrame that your are looking for. Running your code as shown below will help you understand the resulting data structure from applying `groupby()` to a `DataFrame`:

```
groups = df.group('A')
for group in groups:
    # get group key
    key = group[0]
    # Get group df 
    group_df = group[1]
```

Notice that I replaced `group = df.group('A')` with `groups = df.group('A')`