# How to display GroupBy Count as Bokeh vbar for categorical data

Tags: bokeh, pandas-groupby

I have a small issue creating a Bokeh **vbar** in 0.13.0
from a dataframe `groupby` `count` operation. The response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46343429/how-use-bokeh-vbar-chart-parameter-with-groupby-object) was for a multi level group by where as mine isn't.

#### Updates since posting

- added sample data and code based on provided answer to see if issue is my code or something else

#### Outline

The pandas dataframe contains survey responses

- Excellent
- Good
- Poor
- Satisfactory
- Very Good

under columns `('ResponseID','RateGeneral','RateAccomodation','RateClean','RateServices')`and the dtype as been set as catagory. I want to display a bokeh vbar of the Response Count groupby using

```
DemoDFCount = DemoDF.groupby('RateGeneral').count()
```

My bokeh code looks like this

```
pTest= figure(title='Rating in General',plot_height=350)
pTest.vbar(width=0.9,source=DemoDFCount, x='RateGeneral',top='ResponseID')
show(pTest))
```

but doesn't produce any chart only a title and toolbar
[image: Bokeh]

If I use pandas `DemoDFCount.plot.bar(legend=False)` I can plot something but how do I create this chart in bokeh?
[image: dataframe bar plot]

### Sample data as json export

50 rows of sample data from `DemoDF.to_json()`

```
'{"ResponseID":{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":6,"6":7,"7":8,"8":9,"9":10,"10":11,"11":12,"12":13,"13":14,"14":15,"15":16,"16":17,"17":18,"18":19,"19":20,"20":21,"21":22,"22":23,"23":24,"24":25,"25":26,"26":27,"27":28,"28":29,"29":30,"30":31,"31":32,"32":33,"33":34,"34":35,"35":36,"36":37,"37":38,"38":39,"39":40,"40":41,"41":42,"42":43,"43":44,"44":45,"45":46,"46":47,"47":48,"48":49,"49":50},"RateGeneral":{"0":"Good","1":"Satisfactory","2":"Good","3":"Poor","4":"Good","5":"Satisfactory","6":"Excellent","7":"Good","8":"Good","9":"Satisfactory","10":"Satisfactory","11":"Excellent","12":"Satisfactory","13":"Excellent","14":"Satisfactory","15":"Very Good","16":"Satisfactory","17":"Excellent","18":"Very Good","19":"Excellent","20":"Satisfactory","21":"Good","22":"Satisfactory","23":"Excellent","24":"Satisfactory","25":"Good","26":"Excellent","27":"Very Good","28":"Good","29":"Very Good","30":"Good","31":"Satisfactory","32":"Very Good","33":"Very Good","34":"Very Good","35":"Good","36":"Excellent","37":"Satisfactory","38":"Excellent","39":"Good","40":"Good","41":"Satisfactory","42":"Very Good","43":"Very Good","44":"Poor","45":"Excellent","46":"Good","47":"Excellent","48":"Satisfactory","49":"Good"},"RateAccomodation":{"0":"Very Good","1":"Excellent","2":"Satisfactory","3":"Satisfactory","4":"Good","5":"Good","6":"Very Good","7":"Very Good","8":"Good","9":"Satisfactory","10":"Satisfactory","11":"Excellent","12":"Satisfactory","13":"Excellent","14":"Good","15":"Very Good","16":"Good","17":"Excellent","18":"Excellent","19":"Very Good","20":"Good","21":"Satisfactory","22":"Good","23":"Excellent","24":"Satisfactory","25":"Very Good","26":"Excellent","27":"Excellent","28":"Good","29":"Very Good","30":"Very Good","31":"Very Good","32":"Excellent","33":"Very Good","34":"Very Good","35":"Very Good","36":"Excellent","37":"Satisfactory","38":"Excellent","39":"Good","40":"Excellent","41":"Poor","42":"Very Good","43":"Very Good","44":"Poor","45":"Excellent","46":"Satisfactory","47":"Excellent","48":"Good","49":"Good"},"RateClean":{"0":"Excellent","1":"Excellent","2":"Satisfactory","3":"Good","4":"Excellent","5":"Very Good","6":"Very Good","7":"Excellent","8":"Excellent","9":"Satisfactory","10":"Satisfactory","11":"Excellent","12":"Good","13":"Good","14":"Excellent","15":"Excellent","16":"Good","17":"Excellent","18":"Excellent","19":"Excellent","20":"Good","21":"Very Good","22":"Poor","23":"Very Good","24":"Satisfactory","25":"Very Good","26":"Excellent","27":"Good","28":"Poor","29":"Good","30":"Excellent","31":"Good","32":"Good","33":"Very Good","34":"Satisfactory","35":"Good","36":"Excellent","37":"Satisfactory","38":"Excellent","39":"Good","40":"Very Good","41":"Satisfactory","42":"Excellent","43":"Excellent","44":"Very Good","45":"Excellent","46":"Good","47":"Excellent","48":"Good","49":"Excellent"},"RateServices":{"0":"Very Good","1":"Excellent","2":"Good","3":"Good","4":"Excellent","5":"Good","6":"Good","7":"Very Good","8":"Good","9":"Satisfactory","10":"Satisfactory","11":"Excellent","12":"Good","13":"Very Good","14":"Good","15":"Excellent","16":"Poor","17":"Excellent","18":"Excellent","19":"Excellent","20":"Good","21":"Good","22":"Very Good","23":"Excellent","24":"Satisfactory","25":"Very Good","26":"Excellent","27":"Very Good","28":"Good","29":"Excellent","30":"Very Good","31":"Excellent","32":"Good","33":"Excellent","34":"Very Good","35":"Very Good","36":"Excellent","37":"Satisfactory","38":"Excellent","39":"Good","40":"Very Good","41":"Satisfactory","42":"Excellent","43":"Excellent","44":"Good","45":"Excellent","46":"Very Good","47":"Excellent","48":"Good","49":"Very Good"}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it is multi-level in the other question is not really relevant. When you use a Pandas `GroupBy` as a data source for Bokeh, Bokeh uses the results of `group.describe` (which includes counts for each column per group) as the contents of the data source. Here is a complete example that shows Counts-per-Origin from the "cars" data set:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

output_file("groupby.html")

df.origin = df.origin.astype(str)
group = df.groupby('origin')

p = figure(plot_height=350, x_range=group, title="Count by Origin",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

# using yr_count, but count for any column would work
p.vbar(x='origin', top='yr_count', width=0.8, source=group)

p.y_range.start = 0
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Would using `count()` in the groupby make any difference? when I use describe on my group it mentions `<bound method NDFrame.describe` where as in the sample data its ```<bound method GroupBy.describe of <pandas.core.groupby.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy object``` Also I get a plot area but no bars and if I include `x_range =group` in `figure` I get an error

Comment: You need a newer version of Bokeh then, being able to pass a group directly as the range is a new-ish feature. Alternatively you can pas a list of the factors for the range (i.e. the group names) manually.

Comment: My version is reported with `bokeh.__version__ ` as 0.13.0 and with  `output_notebook()` as  BokehJS 0.13.0 successfully loaded.

Comment: I suppose open a new SO question or GH issue then, I don't have any idea offhand why passing a GroupBy would result in an error without seeing actual code.